# How to spin wheel thrice after every hour in android

Tags: android, timer

I have created a spin wheel game in android and want to allow the user to play 3 times in an hour i.e. to play 3 times after every hour within 24 hours.
I am not able to achieve this logic.
I have written this code and applied onclick listener on play button.

```
      findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //PrefManager prefManager=new PrefManager(SpinWheel.this);

                if (enableButton) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                    long previousTime = settings.getLong("time", 0);
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (previousTime == 0) {
                        //prefManager.setCount(1);
                        int index = getRandomIndex();
                        luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putLong("time", (System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        editor.commit();
                        return;
                    }

                    long diff = currentTime - previousTime;
                    //Toast.makeText(SpinWheel.this, "diff: "+diff+"prefCount: "+click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     if (diff>=3600000)
                    {
                        int click=1;
                        Toast.makeText(SpinWheel.this, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (click<=3)
                        {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putLong("time", (System.currentTimeMillis()));
                            editor.commit();
                            int index = getRandomIndex();
                            luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
                          //prefManager.setCount(2);
                            click++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Dialogs.errorDialog(SpinWheel.this, getString(R.string.limit), "You can only play thrice in an hour.", false, false, "", getResources().getString(R.string.ok2), new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }


                    else {
                        /*AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SpinWheel.this).create();
                        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.limit));
                        alert.setMessage("You can only play once in an hour.");
                        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                        alert.setButton(getString(R.string.ok2), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();

                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();*/
                        Dialogs.errorDialog(SpinWheel.this, getString(R.string.limit), "You can only play once in an 3 hour.", false, false, "", getResources().getString(R.string.ok2), new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    Log.i("TAG", "difference " + diff);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SpinWheel.this, R.string.watch_to_play, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I am not getting this condition true and it is not giving me the required result. How the required result will be attained?
I have searched everywhere but not found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that you have declared your click count inside of the condition:

```
                if (diff>=3600000)
                {
                    int click=1;
                    Toast.makeText(SpinWheel.this, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              // You need to do a loop here that increments click     
                    if (click<=3)
```

'click' will always be = 1 because you have just declared and initialized it and you are not looping anywhere.  You need some code to loop while 'click' <= 3.  First, you should probably declare your int click variable either at the top of the onClick method, or even at the class level to broaden its scope, then manage setting it from 3 back to 1 at the termination of your loop.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve it.. e.g. with timer?

Comment: A timer could be helpful, but that means that your app has to be running all day long, which almost never happens.  I think you first have to think of all of the possible 'use cases'. Such as, 'when the user clicks the button, you read from the Shared preferences.  If the last play date is on a previous date, reset the play date to today and reset the click count to 1 and play', 'if the play date is today, and the click count < 3 then play and increment the click count', 'if the play date is today and the click count >= 3 don't play'.  Check on start up and/or on click event.